# How to identity existing item in ArrayAdapter<string>

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am adding the device list to the ArrayAdapter and show it in ListView, where device list is getting from the Bluetooth scan, the scanned devices first add to the arrayadapter. Then later i am adding it to the listview to show the list of scanned bluetooth devices to user.
 But when i am scanning for the devices, duplicate device is adding, suppose a device `A` is scanned means then again two or three times its showing device `A`. I want to show the list of scanned device only one time. How to achieve it. Sorry if question is vague.

Following code is for enquire new devices and adding it to arrayadapter:

```
if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action))
        {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED)
            {
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            }
        // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
            setTitle(R.string.select_device);
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            }
        }
```

Its an program in Android example of version 4.1, example name is `Bluetooth Chat`. Where activity is `DeviceListActivityScan.java`.

Comment: Please post your code here, so that we can see where you are doing it wrong..

Comment: Use Set with ArrayAdapter. Or try to localize bug where dublicate begins

Comment: try to clear your data in ArrayAdapter before scanning

Comment: arrayadapter requires list, not set. you need to use the getPosition method and override the equals method of your items

Comment: @zetsin: First time no problem, for one time scan itself it adding multiple times.

Comment: call mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.clear() before add()

Comment: @zetsin: now also it adding multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run this demo in my two phones, only one will scan multiple times.
so i guess it is relating to the devices.

u can do that to avoid it:

```
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                String deviceInfo = device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress();
                if(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getPosition(deviceInfo) < 0) {
                    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(deviceInfo);
                }
            }
```

Comment: I tried your coding, but its nothing added now. Means no device is shown.

Comment: Yeah, i tested it, its work on phone only, but when coming to emulator, its showing the device name multiple times... Thanks for your answer....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I store to display Bluetooth devices and their signal strengths.

Since RSSI value updates come often, it checks if the Bluetooth device is present in the List already in the `addDevice` method - and only updates the RSSI value in that case:

```
public class DeviceListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView signalImage;
        TextView deviceName;
        TextView deviceAddress;
    }

    private LayoutInflater mInflator;
    // for each BLE device address store the RSSI value and name
    private Map<String, Integer> mRssi = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    private Map<String, String> mName = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public DeviceListAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowlayout);
        mInflator = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public void addDevice(String address, String name, int rssi) {
        if (mRssi.put(address, rssi) == null) {
            // add a new BLE device to the List
            add(address);
            mName.put(address, name);
        } else {
            // just refresh the List after updating RSSI value
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    // return bitmap resource id for a signal strength
    private int rssi2res(int rssi) {
        if (rssi < -100)
            return R.drawable.signal1;

        if (rssi < -75)
            return R.drawable.signal2;

        if (rssi < -50)
            return R.drawable.signal3;

        return R.drawable.signal4;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        // General ListView optimization code.
        if (view == null) {
            view = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, viewGroup, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.signalImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.signalImage);
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceAddress);
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        String address = getItem(i);

        int rssi = mRssi.get(address);
        viewHolder.signalImage.setImageResource(rssi2res(rssi));

        String name = mName.get(address);
        viewHolder.deviceName.setText(name);

        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(address);
        return view;
    }
}
```